# Symbols have mismatching columns error which loading data into vectorbt from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, vectorbt

I have downloaded historical data and stored in a csv file on disk. I am loading this csv file in a pandas dataframe. From there on, I am trying to load this dataframe into vectorbt. Here is my code

```py
import vectorbt as vbt
import pandas as pd

prices_1m = pd.read_csv('../hist/eurusd_m1.csv',
                        index_col='timestamp')

prices_1m.index = pd.to_datetime(prices_1m.index)



vprices_m1 = vbt.Data.from_data(prices_1m)
#vprices_m1 = vbt.YFData.download('AAPL', missing_index='drop')

print(prices_1m.items())
```

But I am getting the following error when I run this code

`ValueError: Symbols have mismatching columns`

What am I doing here?

Comment: Please add the first few lines of the csv file or a link to the file to the question.

Answer (score 0):

For what I undestand, you must imput a dictionary to the from_data() funct
something like this in your case:

```
vprices_m1 = vbt.Data.from_data({'eurusd':prices_1m})
```